# How to stop Twilio filtering user entered DTMF

Tags: twilio, dtmf

I'm using Twilio to forward calls to "local" freephone numbers across the world to an IVR system local to us.

The problem is that this doesn't work, because you need to be able to press numbers to navigate the IVR system, but if you dial via a Twilio number, it seems to filter DTMF tones going through it, so they don't get passed to the end system.

Is there a way to turn off this filtering?

I tried writing a little app to deal with it by moving the basics of the IVR into this app/Twilio, and then it works - except it has to Dial the "real" IVR system and then [`sendDigits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits) to press the right buttons based onwhat the user inputted, however these tones are ignored by our IVR system.  Grrr.  Not sure why, I'm guessing it doesn't play the tones for long enough?

Any ideas for getting it sorted?  It's an IVR for emergency medical assistance, so it's critical it's working (and it's in production now!!).

```
<Response><Dial timeout="180" record="record-from-ringing"><Number sendDigits="wwww1">+<my number></Number></Dial></Response>
```

Should work, but doesn't.  And it wouldn't matter anyway if I could press a button on my phone and it go through!!

Comment: That's quite strange behaviour. I'd recommend getting in contact with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to see if they can discuss this issue with you in a bit more detail.

Comment: I have done, but no response 4 days later...!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Drop me an email at philnash@twilio.com with your ticket number and I'll see if I can find out what's going on.

Comment: @PeteStorey how did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [see here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/what-dtmf-types-do-you-support) for the types of DTMF tones we support.

It is likely that you're experiencing filtering from the carrier end. And this is absolutely something best handled on the support level where you can share [Call Sids](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties) that display the undesired behavior.

There doesn't appear to be anything out of place in your [IVR setup as you describe it](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits). If others need to set one up from scratch, I'd recommend the following tutorial (C#, Java,  Node.js,  PHP,  Ruby):

https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/ivr-screening/ruby/rails#0.

I do hope this helps your Emergency Medical Assistance to be up and running soon!